# Example of algorithm which has different worst case upper bound, worst case lower bound and best case bounds?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Is there any algorithm A, such that for a set of worst case instances S for A, A has different worst case upper bound and worst case lower bound? Moreover it should have different best case bounds not equal to any worst case bounds,for some set of inputs.

For example say H is a hypothetical algorithm such that H has worst case upper bound Ο(n^3), worst case lower bound Ω(n^2) and best case running time Θ(n).

Let me know that above situation is actually meaningful or not?

Thanks :)

Comment: It's just me or worst case lower bound and best case running time will always be the same?

Comment: *The* lower/upper bound does not exist. 5 is a lower bound for the human population, and 10^1000 is an upper bound for the human population. They're just not very accurate bounds.

Comment: @delnan How it is related to question asked? I didn't get it!!

Comment: Lower bounds can be arbitrarily small and upper bounds can be arbitrarily large. So there are always upper and lower bounds that differ. For any algorithm, if Θ(f(n)) is a tight bound for that algorithm, then `f(n)` is a lower bound and `f(n) * n` is an upper bound and they're different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a less natural but perhaps more satisfying definition of `H`. This function computes the cube of the sum of the input list in a rather silly manner.

```
def H(lst):
    s1 = 0
    for x in lst:
        s1 += x
    if s1 == 0:
        return 0
    elif len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        s2 = 0
        for x in lst:
            for y in lst:
                s2 += x * y
        return s1 * s2
    else:
        s3 = 0
        for x in lst:
            for y in lst:
                for z in lst:
                    s3 += x * y * z
        return s3
```

The best-case bound is Theta(n). The tightest worst-case upper bound of the form O(n^k) is O(n^3). The tightest worst-case lower bound of the form Ω(n^k) is Ω(n^2).

Note, however, that the *tightest* bound of any form on the worst-case is Θ(f(n)) where f(2m) = m^2 and f(2m+1) = m^3.

Answer (score 4):

The way you describe it, pick any quadratic sort algorithm, say bubble sort:

- Worst case upper bound can be said to be `O(n^3)`.
- Worst case lower bound can be said to be `Ω(n^2)`.
- The best case running time can be said to be `Θ(n)`, when the input is already sorted
  and you check this with a single pass before starting the algorithm, or use
  optimizations that terminate the algorithm prematurely in this case.

Comment: Do you have an example which causes bubble sort to run in O(n^3) time?

Comment: @RontogiannisAristofanis - big-oh is an upper bound. It runs in O(n^2), O(n^3) and even O(n^3242) all at the same time.

Comment: Worst case is if input is sorted backwards