# How can the worst case for an algorithm have different bounds?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I've been trying to figure this out all day. Some other threads address this, but I really don't understand the answers. There are also many answers that contradict one another.

I understand that an algorithm will never take longer than the upper bound and never be faster than the lower bound. However,  I didn't know an upper bound existed for best case time and a lower bound existed for worst case time. [This question really threw me in a loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835500/example-of-algorithm-which-has-different-worst-case-upper-bound-worst-case-lowe) I can't wrap my head around this... a given run time can have a different upper and lower bound?

For example, if someone asked: "Show that the worst-case running time of some algorithm on a heap of size n is Big Omega(lg(n))". How do you possibly get a lower bound, any bound for that matter, when given a run time?

So, in summation, an algorithm's worst case upper bound can be different than its worst case lower bound? How can this be? Once given the case, don't bounds become irrelevant? Trying to independent study algorithms and I really need to wrap my head around this first.

Answer (score 0):

The meat of my accepted answer to that question is a function whose running time oscillates between n^2 and n^3 depending on whether n is odd. The point that I was trying to make is that sometimes bounds of the form O(n^k) and Omega(n^k) aren't sufficiently descriptive, even though the worst case running time is a perfectly well defined function (which, like all functions, is its own best lower and upper bound). This happens with more natural functions like n log n, which is Omega(n^k) but not O(n^k) for k ≤ 1, and O(n^k) but not Omega(n^k) for k > 1 (and hence not Theta(n^k) regardless of how we choose a constant k).

Comment: It wasn't so much your answer. I'm still not sure how you could have an algorithm with a worst case upper bound of O(n^3) and a worst case lower bound of Ω(n^2).

Comment: @sdeastcott It's also O(n^4) and O(n^5) and Omega(n^1.5) and... We just don't have the right function to get a Theta bound.

Answer (score 0):

Big O notation, describes efficiency in runtime iterations, generally based on   size of an input data set.
The notation is written in its simplest form, ignoring multiples or additives, but keeping exponential form. If you have an operation of `O(1)` it is executed in constant time, no matter the input data.

However if you have something such as `O(N)` or `O(log(N))`, they will execute at different rates depending on input data.

The high and low bounds describe the largest and least iterations, respectively, that an algorithm can take.

Example: `O(N)`, high bound is largest input data and low bound is smallest.

Extra sources:
[Big O Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com) and [MIT Lecture Notes](http://web.MIT.edu/16.070/www/lecture/big_o.pdf)

UPDATE:
Looking at the Stack Overflow question mentioned above, that algorithm is broken into three parts, where it has 3 possible types of runtime, depending on data. Now really, this is three different algorithms designed to handle for different data values. An algorithm is generally classified with just one notation of efficiency and that is of the notation taking the least time for ALL possible values of N.

In the case of **O(N^2)**, larger data will take exponentially longer, and having a smaller number will proceed quickly. The algorithm determines how quickly a data set will be run, yet bounds are given depending on the range of data the algorithm is designed to handle.

Comment: So, to clarify: Your example is saying that the upper bound of O(N) represents how large N can be and still maintain a O(N) runtime, and the lower bound is the smallest size of N that will have a O(N) runtime? Still not very sure.

Comment: Does O(N) represent best or worst case?

Comment: Please see edit, an algorithm is generally classified by one runtime notation and you can have best or worst bounds that are different algoritms for different data values, producing the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you write a program like this to find the smallest prime factor of an integer:

```
function lpf(n):
  for i = 2 to n
    if n%i == 0 then return i
```

If you run the function on the number 10^11 + 3, it will take 10^11 + 2 steps. If you run it on the number 10^11 + 4 it will take just one step. So the function's best-case time is O(1) steps and its worst-case time is O(n) steps.

Comment: Alright, I think I got that. Do you know of a simple example where the best case time would have a different upper and lower bound? Or worst case.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain it in the quicksort algorithm.
In quicksort you have an array and choose an element as pivot. The next step is to partition the input array into two arrays. The first one will contain elements < pivot and the second one elements > pivot. 
Now assume you will apply quicksort on an already sorted list and the pivot element will always be the last element of the array. The result of partition will be an array of size n-1 and an array oft size 1 (the pivot element). This will result in a runtime of O(n*n). Now assume that the pivot element will always split the array in two equal sized array. In every step the array size will be cut in halves. This will result in O(n log n). I hope this example will make this a bit clearer for you. 
Another well known sort algorithm is mergesort. Mergesort has always runtime of O(n log n). In mergesort you will cut the array down until only one element is left und will climb up the call stack to merge the one sized arrays and after that merge the array of size two and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you implement a set using an array. To insert a element you simply put in the next available bucket. If there is no available bucket you increase the capacity of the array by a value `m`.

For the insert algorithm ***"there is no enough space"*** is the worse case.

```
 insert (S, e)
   if size(S) >= capacity(S) 
     reserve(S, size(S) + m)
   put(S,e)
```

Assume we never delete elements. By keeping track of the last available position, `put`, `size` and `capacity` are `Θ(1)` in space and memory.

What about `reserve`? If it is implemented like [realloc in C][1], in the best case you just allocate new memory at the end of the existing memory (best case for reserve), or you have to move all existing elements as well (worse case for reserve).

- The **worst case lower bound for `insert` is the best case of
  `reserve()`**, which is linear in `m` if we dont nitpick. `insert` in
  worst case is `Ω(m)` in space and time.
- The **worst case upper bound for `insert` is the worse case of
  `reserve()`**, which is linear in `m+n`. `insert` in worst case is
  `O(m+n)` in space and time.