# lower bound worst case and lower bound best case in algorithmic complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computer-science, complexity-theory

I figured that finding the upper bound worst-case makes sense most of the time because that's how we get an idea of the maximum runtime of an algorithm, and we can expect that a given algorithm will never exceed that limit. But, as opposed to that, when do we use lower bound worst-case and lower bound best-case analysis? And why?

I have seen the answers to this question [Example of algorithm which has different worst case upper bound, worst case lower bound and best case bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25835500/example-of-algorithm-which-has-different-worst-case-upper-bound-worst-case-lowe) but could not understand why would one need to calculate Ω and Θ when the O gives a clear idea of the complexity.

**EDIT**

---

My question is not about where we are using the lower bounds, I have seen a couple of examples about that. My question is why and when would one choose lower bound (omega) over upper bound (Big O) to determine the worst case.

Is it because

> lower bound immediately gives some bound on the runtime even if we
> haven’t analyzed the algorithm in-depth?

For example suppose the Upper bound worst case of an algorithm is `O(n!)`, and I have not analyzed the algorithm in-depth but found the lower bound worst-case already `Ω(2^n)` then instead of going further, I can conclude that the runtime complexity worst case is `Ω(2^n)`, i.e., tits already bad and we need optimization if possible

Comment: In my experience, it's usually to argue that a complicated recursive algorithm (where it's difficult to get an exact time bound) is slow.

Comment: `O` doesn't give a clear idea of the complexity. It's `Θ` that gives a clear idea of the complexity, because it's both an upper bound and lower bound. However, there are some algorithms that don't have a `Θ`. For those algorithms, you need to find a **tight** `Ω` and `O` to get the complete picture of the algorithm's performance. However, in most cases, only the worst case performance (given by `O`) is of interest, so that's why `O` is the most commonly cited performance metric.

Comment: @user3386109 if `Θ` (the tight bound) gives a clear idea of the complexity of an algorithm then for the worst-case why don't we consider `Θ(g(n))` instead of `O(g(n))`, for example, the algorithmic time complexity of find max element in an unsorted array is `Θ(n)` instead of  `O(n)`

Comment: more precisely why don't we use tight bound at least where it (the `Θ`) is applicable. "However, in most cases, only the `worst-case` performance (given by `O`) is of interest, so that's why `O` is the most commonly cited performance metric." I understand that part as well my question is then why `Ω` when `O` is the most commonly cited performance metric.

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an example. Suppose someone says “I have an algorithm that lists all the subsets of an n-element set” and we want to see how long it will take to run. Since an n-element set has 2<sup>n</sup> different subsets, the runtime of the algorithm must be at least Ω(2<sup>n</sup>), since anything faster than that can’t list all those subsets. This is a lower-bound on the worst-case runtime of the algorithm, and we don’t even need to see what the algorithm is to derive it. If our goal is to say “yeah, that’s definitely not going to be fast enough, because our input has thousands of items in it” we can probably just call it here without looking into the specifics of the algorithm.

Another example would be in cases where there are known lower bounds on a problem. For example, if someone invents a new comparison-based sorting algorithm, we can say that the runtime in the worst case is Ω(n log n). It might be much worse than this, but it’s definitely going to take at least that much time.

Comment: thanks for explaining but I have got two questions, 

1. for the same algorithm which lists all the subsets of an n-element set, the runtime of the algorithm would be,  upper bound `O(2^n)` and  tight bound  `Θ(2^n).`
It satisfies this equation `c1*g(n) <=f(n)<=c2*g(n)` hence `Ω(2n)`,`Θ(2^n)`,`O(2^n)` all of them are correct ie. Lower (at least) == Tight  == Upper then why would you say must be at least Ω(2n) instead of "the exact tight bound complexity of this algorithm" is `Θ(2^n)` or "the upper bound time complexity" is `Θ(2^n).`

Comment: 2. I have seen several examples on the internet just like the second example you gave. Honestly, I am not getting the idea behind `Ω(g(n))` when one can calculate the upper bound worst-case `O(g(n))`.

Comment: For (1), it would depend a bit on how the algorithm was implemented. It’s not hard to write an algorithm for listing subsets that does a really bad job and, say, lists the same subsets multiple times. (This is a common bug my students encounter when learning recursion for the first time!) In that case, it might be a lot harder to get an exact lower bound. Also, I don’t believe you can list all subsets in Theta(2^n) time because of the cost of writing out the elements of those subsets - it takes more than O(1) time to list a set with up to n elements.

Comment: That means that our exponential lower bound is probably good enough here if we want to convince ourselves it’s too slow for n = 1000, even if we have no idea what the exact bounds are.

Comment: For (2), again, it depends on the algorithm. Some comparison sorts do take time O(n log n). Others take time Theta(n^2) in the worst case. The idea of using the sorting lower bound is that it immediately gives some bound on the runtime even if we haven’t analyzed the algorithm in depth.

Comment: Theta notation simply means “whatever quantity I’m describing grows asymptotically at the following rate.” So I can say “I have found a lower bound on the worst-case runtime that’s Theta(n^2 log n)” without it necessarily being the case that the worst case runtime truly is Theta(n^2 log n). In the example you gave, no, you couldn’t conclude the worst-case runtime is Theta(2^n), since the lower bound you have here might not be tight.

Comment: actually, I mistyped in my previous comment  I wanted  to type Ω not Θ

Comment: I am deleting my previous comments and re-writing them.

Comment: Thanks! "The idea of using the sorting lower bound is that it immediately gives some bound on the runtime even if we haven’t analyzed the algorithm in-depth" That makes sense to me now. And this is true for all the cases where to calculate the algorithmic time complexity we use `Ω` notation right?

Comment: For example, suppose the `Upper bound worst case` of an algorithm is `O(n!)`, and I have not analyzed the algorithm in-depth but found the lower bound worst-case already `Ω(2^n)` then instead of going further, I can conclude that the runtime complexity worst case is `Ω(2^n)`, i.e., tits already bad and we need optimization if possible. Will that be correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235082/discussion-between-arko-and-templatetypedef).

Comment: would you please let me know if my understanding is right or there is something else to consider